# angular : duplicate in calling controller's function

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have following angular code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        Test : {{mytest()}} 
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.name= "John ";

            $scope.mytest = function () {
                console.log('my test');
                return 'something';
            };

        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

For more detail, please refer to http://plnkr.co/edit/UIu50AOLMwKIJnAphIB5

Problem: when view in Chrome browser 'Inspect Element' console, the function 'my test' is called **3 times**! Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've asked angular to do that. This expression

```
{{mytest()}}
```

Is in fact instruction:

> "angular, do check if the result value of `mytest()` is not changing. And do that regularly".

And angular is checking that few times, to be sure that it is not changed. And later, in some other digest it will do the same again

so, rather trigger that method once, and let angular to watch the resulting expression, like with a `name` above

```
{{name}}
```

Comment: Really interesting!! Thanks Radim!

Comment: Any idea how to fix this problem ?

Comment: There are many ways. Really. Because it depends on your needs, on the effect which you want to reach. E.g. if you need to evaluate that only once, you can try this http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html and syntax `{{::myTest()}}`

Comment: Great. I think that is the correct answer. Thanks Radim.